# Can Sinn Fein join a minority coalition in a no-confidence vote?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, northern-ireland

I'm just wondering if Sinn Fein having a stated boycott, can enter parliament in a vote of no confidence. It seems to be otherwise consistent with their message. Perpetual no-confidence.

Comment: Just to be clear, who are you assuming would stop them? Or are you actually asking whether they'd have to take the oath of allegiance before voting?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Yes, the question is tagged UK and parliament, and Sinn Fein only have a boycott in that context. The Ireland tag should probably be removed to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to participate in any parliamentary business (including a confidence vote), Sinn Fein MPs would need to [swear an oath to the Crown, or take a solemn affirmation](https://www.parliament.uk/about/how/elections-and-voting/swearingin/):

> Until the oath or affirmation is taken, an MP may not receive a salary, take their seat, speak in debates or vote.

Sinn Fein MPs consistently refuse to do this, so cannot take part in any business of the House of Commons.